# Gimp - Why am I unable to snap to the edges of the brush?

Tags: gimp, brush, snapping, open-source, pencil

When I enable snapping I am unable to snap to the edges of the brush. For example:
[image]

Is There something that I am missing?

[image]

Comment: @kexxgem I'm sorry if the image isn't too clear. In gimp you have the option to snap what you paint to, for example, the canvas edge or a grid. I want my brush to snap flush against the grid instead of it snapping in the middle of the brush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't missing anything. AFAIK you can only snap the center.

If you want to always snap to the same side of the brush, you can define a grid offset

[image]

so that `snap_point ± brush_half_width` is where you want to snap.

For instance, without an offset, grid points are "between pixels" so snapping a 1px splits it over the 4 neighboring pixels:

[image]

And with a .5px offset(as in screenshot above), the grid points are now centered in the pixels, and a 1px brush covers exactly one pixel:

[image]